# case sensitive filter in angular js without using user defined filter

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

can anyone please tell me how to do a case sensitive filter without using user defined filter in angularjs, see here i want to print all the names except `john`, but when i put `filter:{item: '!john'}` it removes `john`, `johnmathew` as well as `johnny`, but i needs only `john` to be removed.

**html**

```
<div ng-app='myApp' ng-controller="Controller">
    <div ng-repeat="val in items | filter:{item: '!john'}">{{val.item}}</div>
</div>
```

**script**

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('Controller', function ($scope) {

    $scope.items = [{
        item: 'john'
    }, {
        item: 'sunny'
    }, {
        item: 'johnmathew'
    }, {
        item: 'lenu'
    }, {
        item: 'binu'
    }, {
        item: 'johnny'
    }];
});
```

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3mgjK/)**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're using a newer version of AngularJS than in your fiddle you could just add `:true` for an exact match.

```
<div ng-repeat="val in items | filter:{item: '!john'}:true">{{val.item}}</div>
```

### Fiddle

If you're not using a newer version you'll have to create your own filter that does the check.

**HTML**

```
<div ng-repeat="val in items | objFilter:'item':'john'">{{val.item}}</div>
```

**JS**

```
app.filter('objFilter', function() {
    return function(input, prop, value) {
        var retValue = [];
        input.forEach(function(item) {
            if(item[prop] && item[prop] !== value) {
                 retValue.push(item);   
            }
        });
        return retValue;
    };
});
```

### Custom filter fiddle